# Is it possible to change when the (Project)-Swift.h header is generated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm facing the following problem :

I've declared an protocol in a Swift file and I want to implement it in Objective-C.
I added the @objc annotation to my protocol so Xcode can generate a definition inside my (Project)-Swift.h file and it works fine.

However I cannot import the (Project)-Swift.h file in any of my objc headers since (I suppose) it is generated after those headers has been processed. It is not a big deal because I can simply use this workaround in my objective header file :

```
@protocol MySwiftProtocolName;
```

It compiles and works just fine but it will also throws a warning for each class that implements my swift protocol :

```
Cannot find protocol definition for MySwiftProtocolName
```

So my question is : Is it possible to force Xcode to generate the (Project)-Swift.h file before it starts processing the regular .h files ?

Thanks

Comment: i think you need to create one swift file that use your swift code. i dont think you can directly use any thirdparty framwork that develop in swift and directly you can use in objective c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add `#import "(Project)-Swift.h"` into the file where you do implementing this swift protocol. Some times Xcode syntax gets funny and not autocomplete this header name, but in compile time it should work.

If it's not could you please provide more context of what is protocol looks like, as it may be not commutable with Objective-C and so it's not get generated at all.